# how to give forms.value .dirty in if condition to the angular reactive form

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular. I am using reactive angular form, in that i have two password fields. I want to update only one password at a time. If someone edits password1 input  field and password2 input field , they tried to update these two in same time means , i should give an alert like- "Update password one by one"

form.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="xyzGroup>
     <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="password" class="col-sm-3">Password1:</label>
                <div class="mx-sm-2 text-center">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control-sm" 
                     formControlName="WifiPassword" [(ngModel)]="password1" id="inputPassword">
                </div>
            </div>
     <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="password" class="col-sm-3">Password2:</label>
                <div class="mx-sm-2 text-center">
                    <input type="password2" class="form-control-sm" 
                     formControlName="WifiPassword2" [(ngModel)]="password2" id="inputPassword">
                </div>
            </div>
<button (click)=onAlert()>Submit</button>
</form>
```

form.component.ts

```
ngOninit(){
this.setFormGroup();
}

 setFormGroup() {
    this.xyzGroup = this.fb.group({
      WifiPassword: "",
      WifiPassword2: "" })
}

onAlert(){
   if(this.xyzGroup.value.WifiPassword.dirty && this.wlanSettingsGroup.value.WifiPassword2.dirty){
   alert("update password once at time")
     }
else{
  here i am using submit method.......
}
```

Here, i don't know this condition inisde if(this.xyzGroup.value.WifiPassword.dirty)  is not working, can anyone help me to this

Answer (score 0):

What looks like is your form is getting submitted and the page is getting refreshed. Because I can see you have a `button` inside a form. When you click on it, it will behave like `type="submit"` button to submit the form.

You can explicitly give it a `type="button"` to not submit the form and It will go inside `onAlert()` method and after validation it will get submitted.

You can try this:

```
<form [formGroup]="xyzGroup">

    <button type="button" (click)="onAlert()">Submit</button>
</form>
```